# Angular mocha test not firing success/error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am currently testing a controller in mocha. The controller has an activate function which should fire success/failure based on the response. I cannot get the failure or success functions to fire during my tests.

viewController.js:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('app')
.controller('viewCtrl', viewCtrl);
function viewCtrl(Service) {
    vm.Service = Service;

    activate();
    function activate() {
        vm.Service.get().then(success, failure);
        function success(data) {
            if (!data || data == 401) {
                failure(data);
            }
        }
        function failure(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("Loading question failed:", error);
                vm.Service.set();
            }
        }
    }
}
})();
```

viewControllerTest.js:

```
describe('question_view_controller', function() {
    var httpBackend, controller;
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var assert = chai.assert;
    var Service = {};
    var createController;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('ui.router');
        angular.mock.module('question');

        Service = {
            set : sinon.stub(),

            get : sinon.stub().returns(Promise.reject({error:{}}));
        }
    })

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend,$controller,$q){
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        createController = function(){
            return $controller('ViewCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                Service: Service
            });;
        }
}));

afterEach(function(){
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

describe('activate', function () {
    describe('get.then() error', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            Service.get.returns(Promise.reject({error:{}}))
        })
        it('should do nothing and setFailedQuestion should be called once', function(){
            vm = createController();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(vm.Service.set.callCount).to.equal('1');
        })

    })

});

});
```

If anyone could point out my mistake or provide any insight that would be great. Anymore questions please ask.

UPDATE:
Edited code to reflect danday74's answer. Still not working.

UPDATE:
Edited code to reflect danday74's comment. Still not working.

Comment: Should `var QuestionService = {};` be `var Service = {};` in your viewControllerTest.js? Otherwise, the "Service" you are declaring in the beforeEach might not be the same "Service" you're accessing elsewhere...

Comment: Yes it should. Will fix now.

Comment: No sorry still not working.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of the problem, but you are also missing `var vm = this;` in the viewCtrl... Does the viewCtrl code work for real (outside the test)?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to call scope digest. you will need to inject $rootScope and then ...

```
vm = createController();
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(vm.Service.set.callCount).to.equal('1');
```

$digest() causes the THEN blocks to be executed.

similar approach to $httpBackend.flush() if you have ever used that.

Comment: Thanks for input. Updated code but "expect(vm.service.get.callCount).to.equal('1')" is still equal to false.

Comment: Service.get.returns(Promise.reject({error:{}})) - this should be inside your create controller function before Service is passed into the controller

Comment: Thanks again for the input. Updated my question to reflect your comment however "expect(vm.service.get.callCount).to.equal('1')" is still equal to false.

Comment: is your activate function getting called? also instead of using Promise most people use Angular's $q.   var def=$q.defer(); def.reject(); return def.promise;  ... also your code AS LISTED HERE still dont reflect my suggested changes (thats fine but it sounded like you were updating your code here to show your latest)

Comment: Yes active gets called. Ifg I call vm.service.set() in active then "expect(vm.service.get.callCount).to.equal('1')" is equal to true. Which changes am I missing exactly. If you tell me I will update. Thanks again for your input.